# How to group all rows in a df which match a specific value in another column in R

Tags: r

For example, my current df looks like this:

| point_id | species | lat\long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AUBC3 | sp1 | 141.345/-15.3455 |
| AUBC3 | sp2 | 141.124/-15.1234 |
| AUBC3 | sp2 | 141.567/-15.3435 |
| AUBC4 | sp3 | 141.5435/-15.3244 |

I'm hoping to then turn it into two separate df looking something like this:

| Point_id | lat/long |
| --- | --- |
| AUBC1 | 141.345/-15.3455 |
| AUBC2 | 141.124/-15.1234 |
| AUBC3 | 141.567/-15.3435 |

(this one with each row corresponding with the same number of point_id's in the above df)

| sp1 | sp2 | sp3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 | 34 |
| 0 | 23 | 7 |

Comment: Instructions unclear – please provide a reproducible example. Specifically I don’t understand what the numbers represent in the second table; how do you get to 17 and 23?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets assume your first dataset is called `tab1`, and the name of the "lat/long" column is `lat.long`. You have inconsistencies with the names of the variables, so I kept the names from the original table.

Your data is not in a friendly format to reproduce it, so I have to scrape it first:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71761992/how-to-group-all-rows-in-a-df-which-match-a-specific-value-in-another-column-in"
tab1 <- read_html(url) %>% html_table() %>% .[1] %>% as.data.frame()
```

And here is the solution to your question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tab2 <- tab1 %>% select(point_id, lat.long) %>% distinct() %>% arrange(point_id)

tab3 <- tab1 %>% select(point_id, species) %>%
  group_by(point_id, species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(sum= n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = point_id, names_from = species, values_from = sum)
```